# RxJava2 Blocking Observable Timeout: How do I emit a result when timeout fires?

Tags: rx-java, observable, blocking, rx-java2

I have an Observable that emits events in the form of JSON strings.  I want to subscribe to it blocking and get the first string.  Not a problem.

But I would like to also have a timeout and emit a canned JSON string when the timeout fires.

Here is my existing code:

```
String jsonString = rxEvents.subscribe().toBlocking().first();
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: The above code works.  It emits the contents of the first event emitted as a string.  The question is how to add a timeout that emits a canned (constant) JSON text string when the timeout fires.

Comment: I'll rephrase. What have you tried to accomplish what you want and how does it not work?

Comment: If I receive an event from my rxEvents Observable before the timer fires, I would like to get that event in jsonString.  If the timeout period elapses I would like to get a jsonString that contains a canned error message.

Answer (score 8):

Just use version of `timeout` that takes 3 parameters:

```
rxEvents
  .timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.just("fallback"))
  .toBlocking()
  .first()
```

Note that in your sample code `subscribe` is not needed.

Comment: This response is towards the solution that I seek, but it does not compile.  The complaint is a type mismatch (Observable<String> vs Observable<? extends String>).

Comment: Can you paste type of rxEvents and return type of the method

Comment: rxEvents is type Observable<String> which contains JSON that goes into a response object back to a user.  In the event of a timeout, I was going to mock up a usable JSON string that gave me the user message that I needed to indicate a timeout.  Observable<String>

Comment: Let me add that in each case (got data, or had a timeout), I just wanted to end up with a type String in which would contain the JSON that went back to the user app.

Comment: This is weird, ideally can you provide full source code of the fragment with as much type info as possible. In any case you can try putting `.cast(String.class)` in correct place (not sure where it should be without seeing the code or more detailed error message) to make it compile. But that should not be necessary if types are as you say.

Comment: I have a message queue object that is in the form of a simple single String that only contains a single JSON object that contains a few fields. 
 At this stage I just treat it as a plain simple Java String.  I have a pending action that awaits the completion message.  That message may take 2 seconds to arrive, or it may have gotten lost.   So, when the result event comes through a queue I want to pass it on as a String, or when the timeout fires, I want a string to contain a timeout message.  I am waiting either for my completion event message or my failure message.

Comment: sorry, this is not helping, can you paste complete isolated piece of code that fails to compile. if type of rxEvents is Observable<String> the answer above will compile. you can append it to your original question.

Comment: The code that I posted in the original question is the full statement in question and works, but not as I need it to work.

Comment: Opps, hit enter.  You were kind enough to post a suggested solution, but that solution does not compile, at least in my environment with RxJava 2.

Comment: public class TestTimeout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<String> rxEvents = Observable.just("one");
        rxEvents
            .timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.just("fallback"))
            .blockingFirst();
    }
}

Does this compile?